# Expectation of Squared Non-Standard Normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X, Y, Z$ be independent standard normal variables. What is $\mathbb{E}(X+Y-Z)^2$?

n.b.: this is review, not homework. I just wanted to double-check my own answer.

Let $Q:=X+Y-Z$. $$\mathbb{E}Q^2 = 3\mathbb{E}(\frac{Q}{\sqrt{3}})^2=3$$

Since $(\frac{Q}{\sqrt{3}})^2$ follows a chi-squared distribution with 1 d.f., i.e. its mean is $1$.

Comment: Correct. You don't actually need the distribution of $Q$ for this.

Comment: In fact, using the distribution of $(Q/\sqrt{3})^2$ and needing to remember the properties of $\chi^2$ random variables is almost the hardest way of solving this problem. Whatever happened to $Q \sim N(0,3)$ (because sum of independent $N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ random variables is $N(\sum_i \mu_i, \sum_i \sigma_i^2)$) and so $E[Q^2] = 3$?

Comment: Thanks @DilipSarwate, but what fact tells us that the expectation of the square of $\mathrm{N}(0,3)$ is $3$?

Comment: $E[X^2]=\sigma_X^2+\mu_X^2$ is a standard identity (applicable to all random variables with finite mean and variance, not just to normal random variables) that you should _memorize_ if you want to make progress in learning probability.